# Is it possible to use MFMessageComposeViewController to view the contents of an outgoing SMS?

Tags: ios

If I use MFMessageComposeViewController to present the SMS compose screen to the user with a pre-populated SMS body then if the user edits the contents of the SMS when the delegate is called:

```
- (void) messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController*) controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result
```

Then controller.body is the original body text, not the altered body text as was sent in the SMS.

Is there anyway of finding out what the sent SMS body text actually was?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, this cannot be done. Even if you iterate through all the subviews of the `MFMessageComposerViewController`'s view you don't get access to the view that the user typed their message into.